# About Random Number Generator in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

The `rand` function in matlab generates a random number between 0-1 with space 0.0001. Is there a way to widen this space so that the number generated is only to the first or second decimal place?? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "with step 0.0001".  Matlab's default random number generator can generate all double precision numbers on the closed internal `[2^-53 , 1 - 2^-53]` ([src](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/04/17/random-number-generator-mersenne-twister/)).  Are you referring to the fact that Matlab displays numbers to only four significant digits by default?

Comment: @Alicia: you did not update/edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate pseudo-random integers between `[0,10^n]` using [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) and divide by `10^n`:

```
randTens     = randi([0,10 ])/10;
randHundreds = randi([0,100])/100;
...
```

Comment: That's because you're multiplying `T_differ` by a number less than `0.10`; the maximum integer and value you divide-by should be the same.  Try this: `T_differ*randi([0,100])/100 + T_lower`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I deleted my previous comment by mistake. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `round` function:http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html

```
Y = round(X,2)
```

> Y = round(X,N) rounds to N digits:
>       N > 0: round to N digits to the right of the decimal point.
>       N = 0: round to the nearest integer.
>       N < 0: round to N digits to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: I am getting this error:`round(x,-3)
Error using round
Too many input arguments.`

Comment: @Alicia Do you have another variable or function called `round`? And why round to 3 digits before the decimal point, when the output from `rand` is always between 0 and 1, the result will always be zero!

Comment: I realized that it's the problem with my version. `round` works fine in r2015a, but not in r2013a. Also, in the case of 3.43*10^-4, is there a way to make it round to 3.4*10^-4? `round` will give me a 0 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I understand Matlab generates uniformly spaced random numbers. If you want to widen the precision step, you could try multiplying `rand` by some value 'a' giving you 0.0001*a spacing and then selecting the numbers that are inferior to 1.